# Google Charts sólo cuándo doy clic al botón se muestra gráfica

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

Les comento que estamos trabajando en un proyecto pero de la nada ya no apareció la gráfica que mostraba resultados de unas consultas. 
[image: Aqui es el incio y no se muestra]

**Ok entonces si yo apretó cualquier botón... taraaa**
[image: ya aparece la grafica]

**Y cuando me meto a la consola me aparece esto**
[image: consola]

```
VM15954:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at <anonymous>:2:7
at m (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at Re (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at w.fn.init.append (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at z (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at w.fn.init.html (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1)
```

Quiero que mi gráfica aparezca al cargar la pagina y no al presionar un botón. Les dejo mi código espero me puedan ayudar gracias!

```
 <table>
            <head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Concepto', 'Resultados', 'Metas'],
      ['Contactos', <?php echo $contactos ?>, 50],
      ['Citas', <?php echo $citas ?>, 25],
      ['Conexiones', <?php echo $conexionr ?>, 5]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Resultados y Metas',
        subtitle: 'de: <?php echo $fecha_desde ?> a: <?php echo $fecha_actual ?> por <?php echo $edat ?>',
      },
        colors: ['#F19D13', '#337ab7']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material2'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
</script>
<div id="columnchart_material2" style="margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left; width: 600px; height: 300px;" ></div>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

mueve el script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

al header, cuando llamas a los scripts en el body se llaman async, por lo tanto el bloque que utiliza la variable google (que la declara ese script) se empieza a ejecutar antes que el script sea ejecutado en su totalidad.

Comment: poner una llamada de un archivo js al header bloqueara el resto del DOM, hasta que este esté listo; los archivos js no son nada recomendables al inicio sino al final del HTML

Comment: tu quieres bloquear el resto del dom, porque dependes de esa variable en el scope global para poder mostrar los graficos, esa es exactamente la razon porque se bloquea la ejecucion del DOM, tu quieres que el resto se ejecute despues de tener eso en memoria.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no funciona amigo. Alguna otra sugerencia.